# Keep the original padding when font weight changes

Tags: html, css

I created two divs with some padding in each of them.

```css
div {
  display:inline;
  background-color:yellow;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

div:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<body style="font:15px arial,sans-serif;"> 
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</body>
```

As seen in the css above, I made the font weight bold when the mouse hovers over the divs.

Now what happens is if I hover over the first div, the second div shifts to the right a little bit due to the additional horizontal space required to accommodate the text with the bold font.

Is there any way to prevent the div from shifting? Can I take the additional space into account even when the font weight is normal (i.e. when the div is not hovered)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The divs will shift because they're meant to fit around the text, so if the text gets bigger, so will the div. Your best bet is to set a fixed width on the div, therefore it won't move.

Answer (score 0):

Either fit the width to be a fixed one or in the hover part reduce the padding.

Comment: `sans-serif` is a user-controlled font-family, so we wouldn't know how much padding to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display : inline;` use `float:left;` and provide a specific amount of `width` to the `div`s

```css
div {
  background-color: #FFFF00;   
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 41px;
}

div:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
```